# Is there a way to maintain IsAjaxRequest() across RedirectToAction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, url-routing

If you don't want any context or an example of why I need this, then skip to **The question(s)** at the bottom!

In a bid to keep things tidy I initially built my application without JavaScript. I am now attempting to add a layer of unobtrusive JavaScript on the top of it.

In the spirit of MVC I took advantage of the easy routing and re-routing you can do with things like `RedirectToAction()`.

Suppose I have the following URL to kick off the sign up process:

> http://www.mysite.com/signup

And suppose the sign up process is two steps long:

> http://www.mysite.com/signup/1
>   http://www.mysite.com/signup/2

And suppose I want, if JavaScript is enabled, the sign up form to appear in a dialog box like ThickBox.

If the user leaves the sign up process at step 2, but later clicks the "sign up" button, I want this URL:

> http://www.mysite.com/signup

To perform some business logic, checking the session. If they left a previous sign up effort half way through then I want to prompt them to resume that or start over.

I might end up with the following methods:

```
public ActionResult SignUp(int? step)
{
    if(!step.HasValue)
    {
        if((bool)Session["SignUpInProgress"] == true)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("WouldYouLikeToResume");
        }
        else
        {
            step = 1;
        }
    }
    ...
}

public ActionResult WouldYouLikeToResume()
{
    if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return View("WouldYouLikeToResumeControl");
    }
    return View();
}
```

The logic in **WouldYouLikeToResume** being:

- If it's an AJAX request, only return the user control, or "partial", so that the modal popup box does not contain the master page.
- Otherwise return the normal view

This fails, however, because once I redirect out of SignUp, `IsAjaxRequest()` becomes false.

Obviously there are very easy ways to fix this particular redirect, but I'd like to maintain the knowledge of the Ajax request globally to resolve this issue across my site.

**The question(s):**

ASP.NET MVC is very, very extensible.

Is it possible to intercept calls to `RedirectToAction` and inject something like "isAjaxRequest" in the parameters?

OR

Is there some other way I can detect, safely, that the originating call was an AJAX one?

OR

Am I going about this the completely wrong way?

Comment: This appears to have been long fixed in MVC. In v5 everything just works as expected, the only problem is that you probably need to add `[OutputCache(Duration = 0)]` to relevant methods, because otherwise the browser might reuse a previous "full" content instead of making an ajax request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As requested by @joshcomley, an automated answer using the TempData approach:

This assumes that you have a BaseController and your controllers are inheriting from it.

```
public class AjaxianController : /*Base?*/Controller
{
    private const string AjaxTempKey = "__isAjax";


    public bool IsAjax
    {
        get { return Request.IsAjaxRequest() || (TempData.ContainsKey(AjaxTempKey)); }
    }


    protected override RedirectResult Redirect(string url)
    {
        ensureAjaxFlag();
        return base.Redirect(url);
    }

    protected override RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
    {
        ensureAjaxFlag();
        return base.RedirectToAction(actionName, controllerName, routeValues);
    }

    protected override RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToRoute(string routeName, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
    {
        ensureAjaxFlag();
        return base.RedirectToRoute(routeName, routeValues);
    }


    private void ensureAjaxFlag()
    {
        if (IsAjax)
            TempData[AjaxTempKey] = true;

        else if (TempData.ContainsKey(AjaxTempKey))
            TempData.Remove(AjaxTempKey);
    }
}
```

To use this, make your controller inherit from AjaxianController and use the "IsAjax" property instead of the IsAjaxRequest extension method, then all redirects on the controller will automatically maintain the ajax-or-not flag.

...

Havn't tested it though, so be wary of bugs :-)

...

Another generic approach that doesn't require using state that I can think of may requires you to modify your routes.

Specifically, you need to be able to add a generic word into your route, i.e.

```
{controller}/{action}/{format}.{ajax}.html
```

And then instead of checking for TempData, you'd check for RouteData["ajax"] instead.

And on the extension points, instead of setting the TempData key, you add "ajax" to your RouteData instead.

See [this question on multiple format route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255876/asp-net-mvc-routes-with-file-extensions) for more info.

Comment: @chakrit - thanks, actually a solution like this had occurred to me whereby I inject the new isAjax parameter in on the overridden RedirectToAction method. But then I (initially) scrapped it due to the fact that when you do something like RedirectToAction("Home", new { id = 1 }), MVC uses reflection to figure out what should be in the route values and I didn't fancy injecting properties into an object. But of course that just boils down to the RedirectToAction() that takes a RouteValueCollection, at which point it should be easy to inject a new value. I was just being a complete moron! Thanks!

Comment: @chakrit (and anyone else) - I've gone down pretty much this route, but without using TempData, which I think is cleaner. I'll probably blog about the final solution in the coming weeks and put a link to the blog on here :) but for all intents and purposes this was the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @joshcomley When you're done don't forget to share it with the rest of us :-)

Comment: I've found bug )))
When you redirecting first time throw ajax it's working normal but if then you open same request url without ajax (past url to browser) it will open like it's ajax
So you should override OnActionExecuting method and add ajax check to resolve it...
Update answer please )

Comment: OnActionExecuting doesn't need it couldn't help
it need to change TempData to ViewData

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.
Please note that this doesn't require any session state which is a potential concurrency issue:

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);

        if (this.Request.IsAjaxRequest)
        {
            if (filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult)
            {
                RedirectToRouteResult rrr = (RedirectToRouteResult)filterContext.Result;
                rrr.RouteValues.Add("X-Requested-With",Request.Params["X-Requested-With"]);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Nice one @crazybert - this is much the best solution to this problem that I've seen.

Comment: I like this a lot. One issue: should Request.Params be Request.Headers (or if you keep params, the key should be "HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH")?

Comment: @jamesfm, this works for months AS IS in my project, so it definitely works as listed above, but maybe there could be more elegant way with headers as well.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can add a AjaxRedirected key in the TempData property before doing the redirection?

Comment: But how can I do this *globally*? Rather than hand code it for this specific example?

Comment: yes, tempdata is the way to do this.  be aware though that tempdata uses session state.  If you have a web farm, you need to deal with that state accordingly

Comment: @josh: you can create an extension method . This extension method will check if IsAjaxRequest() is true or TempData[IsAjaxRequest] is true

Answer (score 0):

One way to transfer state is to add an extra route parameter i.e.

```
public ActionResult WouldYouLikeToResume(bool isAjax)
{
    if(isAjax || Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView("WouldYouLikeToResumeControl");
    }
    return View();
}
```

and then in the Signup method:

```
return RedirectToAction("WouldYouLikeToResume", new { isAjax = Request.IsAjaxRequest() });

// Don't forget to also set the "ajax" parameter to false in your RouteTable
// So normal views is not considered Ajax
```

Then in your RouteTable, default the "ajax" parameter to false.

Or another way to go would be override extension points in your BaseController (you do have one, right?) to always pass along the IsAjaxRequest state.

..

The TempData approaches are valid too, but I'm a little allergic of states when doing anything that looks RESTful :-)

Havn't tested/prettify the route though but you should get the idea.

Comment: Like I said in my question, there are easy ways to solve it *for this instance* by hand, but what about globally? In fact, my exact question is asking if it is possible to automate your answer!

Comment: @joshcomley one moment... coming up with an *automated* answer :-)

Comment: I agree with what you said about states on something that's RESTful, which is why I am hesitant to go the TempData route. Yep, I do have a "BaseController". "Overriding extension points" sounds like the animal I was after... could you elaborate? :)

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to offer what I believe is a MUCH better answer than the current accepted one.

Use this:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private string _headerValue = "X-Requested-With";

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var ajaxHeader = TempData[_headerValue] as string;
        if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest() && ajaxHeader != null)
            Request.Headers.Add(_headerValue, ajaxHeader);
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest() && IsRedirectResult(filterContext.Result))
            TempData[_headerValue] = Request.Headers[_headerValue];
    }

    private bool IsRedirectResult(ActionResult result)
    {
        return result.GetType().Name.ToLower().Contains("redirect");
    }
}
```

Then make all your controllers inherit from this.

What it does:

Before an action executes this checks to see if there is a value in `TempData`. If there is then it manually adds its value to the `Request` object's header collection.

After an action executes it checks if the result was a redirect. If it was a redirect and the request was an Ajax Request before this action was hit then it reads the value of the custom ajax header that was sent and stores it in temp data.

This is better because of two things.

1. It is shorter and cleaner.
2. It adds the request header to the `Request` object after reading the temp data. This allows `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` to work normally. No calling a custom `IsAjax` property.

Credit to: [queen3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119224/queen3) for his [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588589/firefox-does-not-preserve-custom-headers-during-ajax-request-redirect-an-asp-net) containing this solution. I did modify it to clean it up a bit but it is his solution originally.

Comment: Worth mentioning that Request.Headers.Add() doesn't seem to work using the ASP.NET Development server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283458/adding-custom-request-header-works-for-iis-7-0-but-not-asp-net-dev-server

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is in the Client-Cache. 
To overcome this, just add a cachebreaker
like "?_=XXXXXX" to Location Url in the 302 Response.

Here is my working Filter. Regisiter it in the GlobalFilter Collection.
I added the Location Header to the Redirected Response, so the client script can get the destination url, in the ajax call. (for Google-Analytics)

```
public class PNetAjaxFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        if(request.QueryString["_"] == "ajax")
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
            request.QueryString.Remove("_");
        }
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    //public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var context = filterContext.HttpContext;

        if (!context.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return;

        var request = context.Request;

        String noCacheQuery = String.Empty;

        if (request.HttpMethod == "GET")
        {
            noCacheQuery = request.QueryString["_"];
        }
        else if (context.Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected)
        {
            var pragma = request.Headers["Pragma"] ?? String.Empty;
            if (pragma.StartsWith("no-cache", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                noCacheQuery = DateTime.Now.ToUnixTimestamp().ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                //mode switch: one spezial cache For AjaxResponse
                noCacheQuery = "ajax";
            }
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(noCacheQuery))
        {
            if (context.Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected)
            {
                var location = context.Response.RedirectLocation;

                if (location.Contains('?'))
                    location += "&_=" + noCacheQuery;
                else
                    location += "?_=" + noCacheQuery;

                context.Response.RedirectLocation = location;
            }
            else
            {
                var url = new UriBuilder(request.Url);

                if (url.Port == 80 && url.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
                    url.Port = -1;
                else if(url.Port == 443 && url.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
                    url.Port = -1;

                if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(url.Query))
                    url.Query = String.Join("&", url.Query.Substring(1).Split('&').Where(s => !s.StartsWith("_=")));

                context.Response.AppendHeader("Location", url.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here the jQuery:

```
         var $form = $("form");
         var action = $form.attr("action");
         var $item = $("body");

         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: action,
                data: $form.serialize(),
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    $item.html(data);

                    var source = xhr.getResponseHeader('Location');
                    if (source == null) //if no redirect
                        source = action;

                    $(document).trigger("partialLoaded", { source: source, item: $item });
                }
            });
```