# Request.IsAjaxRequest returns false

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project in which I have a form with a submit button.  I have added a jquery client-side handler that intercepts the form submit event.  The javascript function calls the same MVC action that would have been called without the javascript.

```
 $("form[action ='/List/CreateItem']").submit(
            function() {
                $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(response) { $("#results").html(response); });
                return false;
            }
            );
```

In the MVC action that is called, I test for Request.IsAjaxRequest to decide whether to return a view or a JSON result.  My problem is that Request.IsAjaxRequest is returning false, even though I know the call is being made from the jquery function.  (I know this because if I comment out the $.post line in the jquery function and just leave the return false line, nothing happens.  If I un-comment the line, the action gets executed - but it returns the view because IsAjaxRequest is false.)

Should this line cause Request.IsAjaxRequest to be true?

Comment: $.post *does* set `X-Requested-With` and hence `IsAjaxRequest`

Comment: This post may solve your problem: http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/10/aspnet-mvc-isajaxrequest-jquery.html

Comment: I have seen cases where Request.IsAjaxRequest() randomly returns false when loading multiple page sections via ajax. I started adding a `partial=1` parameter to the queries and `bool partial = Request.IsAjaxRequest() || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["partial"]);` in the controllers to ensure I get partial pages on ajax calls and full pages when browsed.

Answer (score 3):

The `Request.IsAjaxRequest` property should reflect the existence of the `X-Requested-With` HTTP header. Is this header actually sent to the server? As James suggests, try to profile this with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/) or similar proxy server alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Well... I apologize.  I don't know what has changed, but now IsAjaxRequest is returning true.  I compare the code I posted above and what is executing now and I see no difference.  I repeatedly got false on this before, and now I repeatedly get true.  Surely I am missing something, but I don't see it.

Comment: This is insane, but the same just happened for me. Well. I don't mind anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the difference would be but a possible way to identify if there is one is to use an HTTP profiling tool like Fiddler (www.fiddlertool.com) and look for possible differences between the two calls.

Answer (score 0):

Does CreateItem perform redirect? See [Firefox does not preserve custom headers during Ajax request redirect: an ASP.NET MVC solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588589/firefox-does-not-preserve-custom-headers-during-ajax-request-redirect-an-asp-net)