# MVC 3 Ajax.ActionLink not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, unobtrusive-javascript, actionlink

I'm playing around with the some MvcMusicStore example based shop and having some problems with the MVC3 Ajax.ActionLink / Ajax.RouteLink helpers. The problem is that it simply does not generate an Ajax request (Request.IsAjaxRequest() == false). The forms I'm generating using the Ajax.BeginForm / Ajax.BeginRouteForm are working nicely though.

Config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" 
         value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" 
         value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Scripts:

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Link:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("show cart", "Show", "Cart", new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "handleSuccess", HttpMethod = "Get", OnFailure = "handleFailure" })
```

Generate HTML:

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-failure="handleFailure" data-ajax-method="Get" data-ajax-success="handleSuccess" href="/Cart/Show">show cart</a>
```

As said, this works just fine:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
        "Show",
        new { controller = "Cart" },
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            OnSuccess = "handleSuccess",
            OnFailure = "handleFailure"
        }))
    {
        <input type="submit" class="button" />
    }
```

The action looks like this:

```
[Authorize]     
public ActionResult Show()
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        ViewBag.CartItems = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this)
            .Items;

        return Json(new AjaxResultViewModel()
        {
            Content = RenderPartialViewToString(),
            UpdateTargetSelector = "#dialog",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    ViewBag.Exception = new NotSupportedException();
    return View("Error");
}
```

I've been searching for a while now and couldn't find the reason for this behavior, maybe someone could help me out?

Best regards!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a new MVC4 Template on the `_layout.cshtml` close to the bottom, there is a `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`.

I had to include 
`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` which is the Ajax library

This fixed the problem I was having with a full postback using the index page. My action link code:

```
<div id="timeDisplay">
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click to display server time", "Time", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="GET",UpdateTargetId="timeDisplay"});
</div>
```

Comment: I marked this as answer since it seems to solve the problem, even though it's been a while (and a previous version) and i can't test it anymore.

Comment: +1: well done. This kick-started my Ajax.ActionLink (which for no other reason was not firing)

Answer (score 2):

I made it work by declaring the following scripts in this exact order:

```
@section script
{
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript">   </script>
}
```

For the sake of completeness, in my *_Layout.cshtml* file I declared the following:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@RenderSection("script", required:false)

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: The Microsoft JS files have been defunct for a while, and obsolete since MVC3 (they're gone in MVC4). The pre-shipped jQuery ones are the official replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **[ [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752434/request-isajaxrequest-returning-false-on-post) ]** has the answer.

In short: Are the js functions "**handleSuccess**" and "**handleFailure**" ***accessible*** by the form?

Lg
warappa

Comment: Hey Warappa, yes the functions are accessible. And since I can tell from the request header it doesn't even create a proper AJAX request. Guess I'll just stick to using the BeginForm helper instead since that one works. Just not the prettiest solution ;)

Comment: In addition: I already got to know the behavior described in your post the hard way. But I'm quite sure since the 2 test links are generated at the same point in html. The first line fails, the second succeeds. strange ;)

    <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-failure="handleFailure" data-ajax-    success="handleSuccess" href="/Cart/Show">Show cart</a>
    <form action="/Cart/Show" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-    failure="handleFailure" data-ajax-success="handleSuccess" id="form0"     method="post"><a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="show cart" id="show-    cart">show cart</a>            
    </form>