# Request.IsAjaxRequest never returns true in MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using Asp.net MVC3 and trying to do a simple Ajax post to the server which returns a partial view and updates my list of items during a search.

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("PartialUpdate", "Listing"
        , new  AjaxOptions { 
                UpdateTargetId = "ListPartialDiv",
                HttpMethod = "GET",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,

        }))
    {
        <!-- Search Boxes and buttons here -->
    }

    <div id = "ListPartialDiv">
        @{
            Html.RenderPartial("_ListPartial", Model);
         }
    </div>
```

The ajax successfully makes a call to the server and the server responds by sending a partial view. But the partial view always renders in a new page. I found out that this is because it doesn't know that it is an ajax call coming and so it renders a new page. I HAVE included the correct jquery-ubobtrusive-ajax.min.js scripts and added the key as follows according to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164540/why-doesnt-request-isajaxrequest-work-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript">
```

My controller code is very simple:

```
      if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
          return PartialView("_ListPartial", list);

      return View("Index", list);
```

But Request.IsAjaxRequest() always returns false no matter what.
I have also used fiddler and firebug according to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702837/request-isajaxrequest-returns-false) and don't see the X-Requested-With header but I can't really figure out what that means or how to change it. The only thing I can think of is that every other example I see uses an older version of jquery. Does that have anything to do with it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you notice that the browser isn't actually doing an AJAX POST?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're including the unobtrusive-AJAX script before jQuery, so none of your scripts are working.

Comment: Yep was about to type the same answer

Answer (score 1):

```
var controllerContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ControllerContext>();
controllerContext.Expect(c => c.HttpContext.Request["X-Requested-With"]).Return("XMLHttpRequest");
controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the jquery.unobtrusive.ajax.js / jquery.unobtrusive.ajax.min.js script file is referenced after the other jquery script files, also make sure that you dont reference the file more than once per page and you should be sorted

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the unobtrusive script after jquery script like this.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/searchDemo").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on the similar situation where IsAjaxRequest() didn't work. 
I made sure Microsoft unobtrusive package is included. It still didn't help.
Just upgraded to the latest version of unobtrusive library from package manager and it worked!